# definition/resolution image GIMP

Tags: image, gimp

i have a naive question about image definition resolution and dimension on GIMP.

If we take this example :

1)sensor: 4000x3000 =12 000 000 pixels (image definition)
  resolution : 300 ppp (dpi)
  Image dimension will be : 3000/300 x 4000/300 = 10 x 13.3 pouces
  in cm : (10 x 2.54) x (13.3x2.54) = 25.4 x 33.8cm

2)sensor : 4000x3000 =12 000 000 pixels (image definition)
  résolution : 72 ppp (dpi)
  Image dimension : 3000/72 x 4000/72 = 41 x 55 pouces
  in cm : (41 x 2.54) x (55x2.54) = 104 x 141cm ( a bigger width and 
  length)

My question is why when i test these 2 configurations on GIMP, i get 2 images of the same width and length ?

Comment: What image file format is used, and where exactly are the ppi values stored (think Exif vs. XMP vs. file-format-specific meta-data)?

Comment: the format is a simple .PNG. I wanted to test if really the length and width of the image change accordingly to the resolution. In GIMP, the resolution is done with : clik Image->Scale&Dimension->Resolution_X Resolution_Y (pixels/in) and Witdh Height (pixels)

Comment: Ah, I see. The issue isn't that GIMP doesn't display those ppi values, but that you expect it to show the images at their physical sizes (or at least at a different physical size) on your screen. I think this enables me to write an actual answer.

Comment: so, is that possible or not ? :D

Comment: Perfectly possible... one issue with your question is that you asked it on the wrong stackexchange site, though - Stack Overflow is for programming questions. Super User might be a better ones, we can flag it to be transferred.

Answer (score 0):

By default, GIMP uses the image's size in pixels to determine how to display it - 100% zoom if the image fits the screen, zoomed out if it is larger, with the behavior adjustable to some degree in the preferences' Image window section.

Both of your images have the same size in pixels, so they appear as the same size when you open them in GIMP.

When you want their resolution to be taken into account, you have to disable [Dot for Dot](http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-pimping.html#gimp-prefs-image-window) display in the preferences. If you have also set up your screens resolution in GIMP's Display preferences, then the image should be shown at the sizes you expect, at least at 100% zoom.

Comment: yes i understand. However i didn't find the "Dot for Dot display" option. it exists in all versions of GIMP?